# AngularJS ng-if Сравнение даты

Tags: angularjs

Запрашиваю текущую дату и время:

$scope.currentDate = new Date();

Получаю: `"2017-10-04T12:24:42.572Z"`
Затем, при условии хочу вывести `'Test'`:

```
 <p ng-if="currentDate < dev.data_block">Test</p>
```

Где `dev.data_block - 2017-10-04 11:09:51`
Соответственно условие не отрабатывает. Как привести эти значения для сравнения к одному виду?

Comment: так сравнивай даты

Comment: Мне нужно сравнивать дату/время. Как задать формат функции Date(), чтобы он соответствовал -> 2017-10-04 11:09:51 ?

Comment: никак, Date возвращает **объект** даты, а не строку. Но ты можешь использовать pipe date из ангуляра, и ему можешь передать нужный формат

Comment: <p ng-bind="currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'"></p> По формату теперь вроде похоже, но условие <p ng-if="dev.data_block > currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'">123</p> так и не отрабатывает...

Comment: а с чего ему отрабатывать, если ты в нем так и не используешь pipe? :)

Comment: Поправил. Результата 0

Comment: что именно и как поправил-то?

Comment: В сравнение добавил формат вывода даты и времени: <p ng-if="dev.data_block > currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'">123</p> Или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: попробуй в скобки обернуть `ng-if="dev.data_block > (currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!